# Indexing a Apple Help Book on BigSur

Tags: appkit

I'm trying to generate an Apple Help Book index file (Big Sur), I'm using the following scripts:

```
hiutil -I corespotlight -Cf Base.lproj.cshelpindex -a -vv .
hiutil -I lsm -Cf Base.lproj.helpindex -a -vv .
```

Files are generated, but when I validate them I get:

```
Index format no longer supported.
or
Unable to open Archive
```

I've generated the same files with Apple's "Help Indexer" GUI program, but the files too are apparently no-longer supported.

I've read that it apparently works on High-Sierra, but I don't have access to a Mac with that OS.

Is there a known workaround for this? or am I doing it wrong?

The ultimate goal would be to run on GitHub Actions, but I'm limited as I can't run a macOS Virtual Machine on there.

- Maybe I could find the version of hiutil that ran on High Sierra (hiutil version 1.3.2 (55) ?) and run that in a Linux Docker?
- Maybe I could find out the file format of the .helpindex files and write a program to generate them

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have the answer, the commands need to be:

```
hiutil -I corespotlight -Caf Base.lproj.cshelpindex -vv .
hiutil -I lsm  -Caf Base.lproj.helpindex -vv .
```

and to validate

```
hiutil -I corespotlight -Af Base.lproj.helpindex
hiutil -I corespotlight -Af Base.lproj.cshelpindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a virtual machine which runs another os inside your os. This is the easiest way for you: download [Parallels Desktop Lite](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/ca/app/parallels-desktop-lite/id1085114709?mt=12&at=1010loXs&ct=304866) and see [Install MacOS in Parallels Desktop Lite](https://www.howtogeek.com/304866/how-to-make-linux-and-macos-virtual-machines-for-free-with-parallels-lite/#:%7E:text=Install%20macOS%20in%20Parallels%20Desktop%20Lite).

Comment: Is there a solution without using a virtual machine? Is there a different flag combination I need to use to make it work on Big Sur?

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: yeah I have no idea.